# Force FragmentStatePagerAdapter to open to a specific page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a Swipe View/Tab View activity (whatever you want to call it), that opens upon clicking an item in a ListView in the previous activity.  On default, the Swipe View (implemented by a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, as all the data is pulled from a database) opens to the first page, but I want it to open to the page selected in the ListView.  I tried overriding the `setPrimaryItem` method and sending the superclass method with the ListView item index, but it didn't change anything.  I'm sure I'm not the first person to grapple this issue....

This is what I tried so far:

```
@Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        if(firstTab){
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment f = getItem(TourSwipeActivity.this.getIntent().getIntExtra(StationMenuActivity.TOUR_INDEX, 0));
            firstTab = false;
            super.setPrimaryItem(container, TourSwipeActivity.this.getIntent().getIntExtra(StationMenuActivity.TOUR_INDEX, 0), f);
        }else
            super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
};
```

Sending a message to the LogCat, I found that the `if` clause was being entered, but no change in the app.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not just calling `setCurrentItem()` on the `ViewPager`?

Comment: I'll try it out tomorrow. If it does would it's supposed to, then yes, that's just what I meant when I said, "I'm not the first...".  And I'll let you know so you write it up as an 'answer' if your sense of self-worth will let you get away with it...

Comment: I assumed that you had a reason for not choosing the simple option and going down a rather convoluted path, such as `setCurrentItem()` not doing something specific that you were seeking.

Comment: Nope, sometimes if it looks like a fool and talks like a fool, well, then...

Comment: As expected, it works perfectly. If you want your 5 points, post it as an answer! Thanks a bunch!